# What are the merges and vocab files used for in BERT-based models?

Tags: neural-network, nlp, bert

The title says it all. I see plenty online about how to initialize RoBERTa with a merges and vocab file, but what is the point of these files? What exactly are they used for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vocab file contains a mapping from vocabulary strings and indices used for embedding lookup in the model.

The merges say how to split the input string into subword units. The algorithm is as follows: At the beginning of merging, a word split into characters and then you greedily search for neighboring symbols that can be merged (i.e., are in a list of allowed merges), you stop when there is nothing to merge and this is the subword segmentation.

Comment: Okay so I input some text, the merges file is used to break the text down and merge it into some "subword" pieces (maybe, but not necessarily, back into the original text), and then the vocab file is used to encode those pieces as integers?